# AWS EMR local disk encryption failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

EMR instance spinned failed with an error

`Terminated with errors. On the master instance , local disk encryption failed due to internal error.`

Any pointers will be helpfull

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your vpc has access to kms service via Internet gateway of kms end point

Answer (score 1):

Make sure both EMR_DefaultRole and EMR_EC2_DefaultRole are greanted to use the kms key

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/secure-your-data-on-amazon-emr-using-native-ebs-and-per-bucket-s3-encryption-options/

Comment: Replace kms:GenerateDataKeyWithoutPlaintext with kms:GenerateDataKey*

Answer (score 0):

If you enable logging to S3, logs from the disk encryption step will be written to:

`<cluster_id>/node/<master_instance_id>/setup-devices/DiskEncryptor.log.gz`

These logs will provide additional insight into the "internal error".

If you can share that content, someone might be able to provide more detailed help!